# Call derived class from base class (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, oop

I have created a generic base class for keeping track of open forms (router) of a specific form type that also has a generic base.  The problem arises when I need to call a unique derived form method from the derived router class.  Is there anyway to do this? 
Form router base class has
Dictionary(Of String, Forms)
Derived Form router needs to call unique methods of the derived forms stored in this dictionary.  The problem is that visual studio sees the type in the dictionary as the base form class, not the derived form class (but if I do a get type during run time, the object is of the derived form class).

I've tried creating overrideable properties and functions, but the type must be specified in the base class and just using "Object" does not work.

I can post code if need be, but I'm trying to keep this simple and generic.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the value from the dictionary to the derived type:

```
Dim frmDerivedForm As YourDerivedForm = CType(yourDictionary("yourKey"), YourDerivedForm)

frmDerivedForm.DerivedFormMembers()
```

Comment: This is the ticket!  Thanks!  I kept reading that this could not be done and couldn't find the correct way to try it.

Comment: I'm glad that helped.  Please mark this as the accepted answer if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just casting them? (This is not tested)

```
Form form;
if(form is DerivedForm)
    (form as DerivedForm).DerivedField = "asdf";
```

---

```
Form form;
if(form is DerivedForm)
    ((DerivedForm)form).DerivedField = "asdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a protected Overridable (virtual) method in your base class that accepts the data that you need to send to the derived class and returns the data that you need to get from the derived class and then override it in the derived (inherited) class and do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response Doker.  I was looking for a way to not have to modify the base class for every method call to the derived class.  NoAlias's suggestion works.

Comment: Then the visitor pattern is for you. It's heavy but it addresses that requirement exactly